Bricked (?) my Honor 9 Lite (LLD-L31)
Like a year ago I was rooting my device, successfully installed TWRP and Magisk, rooting was completed, I was glad. Some time later, I accidentally updated my phone, thus erased Magisk. Yesterday I was going to root my phone again, downloaded Magisk zip, booted into TWRP, installed that zip, but oops, it told that it has broken some partitions (/system and /vendor as I remember), I rebooted and now it cannot boot. On the usual boot it says
ERROR MODE
Attention! Please update system again
Error!
Func NO : 10 (boot image)
Error NO : 2 (load failed!)

I still can enter eRecovery, but both "Download latest version and recovery" and "Wipe data/factory reset" Are not working. First button lets me connect to a Wi-Fi, then it says "Getting package info from server", after several seconds "Getting package info failed". (I am from Russia, perhaps it is IP block?)
"Wipe data/factory reset" button sometimes just grayed out, but when not, it asks me a confirmation, then reboots into an error screen:
ERROR MODE
Attention!
Please update system again
Error!
Func NO 11 (recovery image)
Error NO 2 (load failed!)

I have access to fastboot, but it cannot even get vars: (getvar:product) failed: 'Command not allowed' (from https://flash.android.com/ website)
It also can flash no partition (tried system, vendor, bootloader, boot).
In fastboot mode it says that Phone unlocked and FRP unlock.

I did not confirm it, but it seems a lot that it's just my memory has broken. My phone is like 7 years old, if I remember correctly, so chances of died memory are high.
